# Polynomials satisfying $p(x)|p(kx)$

Tags: polynomials

I was curious on what type of polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ satisfied $p(x)|p(kx)$ for all integers $k$ and $x$. Which integer polynomials satisfy this claim? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a polynomial $p(x)=\sum a_ix^i \in \Bbb{Z}[x]$. Then $$p(kx)=\sum a_ik^ix^i=a_0+\sum_{i>0} a_ik^ix^i.$$ So, suppose $a_0\ne 0$, since $p(kx)$ and $p(x)$ have same degree and same constant coefficient, $p(x)\mid p(kx)$ iff $p(x)=p(kx)$ for all $k>0$, which never happens, unless $p(x)=a_0$.

Now, if $a_0=0$, by reducing to the previous case, it is easy to show that $p(x)=ax^n$ for some $a\in \Bbb{Z}$, $n>0$.

So the only polynomials that satisfy this are homogeneous polynomials, i.e., polynomials of the form $p(x)=ax^n$ for some $a\in \Bbb{Z}$, $n\geq 0$.